# Reordering stacked bar charts in facet plots based on two conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Background** I currently plot 12 figures in a matrix using facet. However to make this more simple and reproducible i have cut it down to 5 figures
[image]
However, there is no consistency in the order of the graph. Ideally I would like to have all observations in the following order of these bond issuers: NYK > RD > NDA - while also ordering on the Coupon rate. So NYK 1' > NYK 5' > RD 1' > RD 5' > NDA 1' > NDA 5'. Just like this order:

1. NYK 1' 2050, 2. NYK 5' 2053,
2. RD 1'2050,   4. RD 5'2053,
3. NDA 1' 2050

In the data.frame I provide below the Issuers "NYK, RD, NDA" can be seen in the "UdstederKat" column and the coupon rates can be seen in the "KuponRente" column.

So there is a clear order:
Certain issuers needs to be plotted before others - while within these issuers they must be plotted in order to their coupon rate. However, I cant seem to find a sensible way to achieve this. I use the: facet_wrap(~FondskodePlotColumn, strip.position = "bottom") to get all the 7 plots. But, If i try to order on UdstederKat or anything else, it just collapses.

**Rounding up** How do I reorder the facet above showing the 5 unique values for FondskodePlotColumn while ordering them based on their "UdstederKat" variable and "KuponRente" variable?

**Reproducible code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


df <- structure(list(Dato = c("01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", 
"01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", 
"01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", 
"01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "01-23", "04-23", 
"04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", 
"04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", 
"04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", 
"04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", 
"07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", 
"07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", 
"07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", 
"10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", 
"10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", 
"10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", 
"10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", 
"10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23"
), FondskodePlotColumn = c("NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", 
"NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", 
"RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816"
), UdstederKat = c("NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NYK", 
"NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", 
"RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "NDA", 
"NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", 
"NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", 
"RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", 
"NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", 
"NYK", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", 
"RD", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NDA", "NYK", 
"NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", 
"NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "NYK", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", 
"RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD", "RD"), KuponRente = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5), Fondskode = c("DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", 
"DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", 
"DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009539116", 
"DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", 
"DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", 
"DK0004612454", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", 
"DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", 
"DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0009522815", 
"DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", 
"DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", 
"DK0009539116", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", 
"DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", 
"DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0002044551", 
"DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", 
"DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", 
"DK0009522815", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", 
"DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", 
"DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004623816", 
"DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", 
"DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", 
"DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0002044551", "DK0009522815", 
"DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", 
"DK0009522815", "DK0009522815", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", 
"DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", "DK0009539116", 
"DK0009539116", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", 
"DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", "DK0004612454", 
"DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", 
"DK0004623816", "DK0004623816", "DK0004623816"), LoanIntervalMio = c("1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "1: <200K", 
"2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "6: 10M-50M", 
"7: >50M", "1: <200K", "2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", 
"5: 3M-10M", "6: 10M-50M", "7: >50M", "1: <200K", "2: 200K-500K", 
"3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "6: 10M-50M", "7: >50M", 
"1: <200K", "2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", "4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", 
"6: 10M-50M", "7: >50M", "1: <200K", "2: 200K-500K", "3: 500K-1M", 
"4: 1M-3M", "5: 3M-10M", "6: 10M-50M", "7: >50M"), TotalSumNominel = c(8684206, 
296456100, 2232269622, 9175871164, 7211001711, 21139385, 963554858, 
7981246163, 31503777145, 14563702652, 3156932, 278768237, 4097476994, 
19370321649, 3461283667, 15572773, 342364129, 3036016197, 13853455958, 
20275204344, 3572161, 55300970, 630578430, 3399732767, 1802678688, 
9027807, 289995006, 2109651506, 8188785449, 6791996929, 20445574, 
928041208, 7417753055, 27511711672, 13642904914, 6329228, 433602345, 
5910093565, 27863564827, 5387625442, 15490749, 337275038, 2923888955, 
12372421376, 18681780260, 6250759, 80554746, 866462163, 4893622086, 
3046674886, 8579939, 285076815, 2015169331, 7575202048, 6418951519, 
19912525, 913647164, 7004431636, 24730267141, 12613464866, 10310681, 
647581243, 8375799808, 39877546898, 8280276829, 15102174, 337143021, 
2850690169, 11379793908, 17938559074, 8234367, 131253539, 1247785891, 
6950375355, 4697096170, 8550051, 281729420, 1936005121, 7035795941, 
3156399077, 2482010768, 403968492, 19897237, 896791461, 6662324822, 
22748230187, 5324189857, 3813821555, 2848134864, 11791997, 739483826, 
9355283669, 45747488728, 9092835448, 581807316, 475793090, 14805975, 
337885275, 2765790302, 10532362963, 6050595739, 8162446965, 2998613945, 
9910905, 158168368, 1482986996, 8464718080, 3451903164, 1130503065, 
1139165093), PercentageOfTotal = c(0.0458892212212308, 1.56653809862218, 
11.795795091617, 48.4872862000635, 38.1044913884761, 0.0384119048425917, 
1.75085403459528, 14.5025443331703, 57.2448105692742, 26.4633791581176, 
0.011601672604134, 1.02446863540477, 15.0581598169866, 71.1856099556364, 
12.720159919368, 0.0415023677417548, 0.912420799002438, 8.09116402568881, 
36.9202854021644, 54.0346274054026, 0.0606287177807665, 0.938599044984993, 
10.7025303929775, 57.7021692080697, 30.596072636187, 0.0519154057386822, 
1.66764845534265, 12.1317850394024, 47.0905192248629, 39.0581318746534, 
0.0412867940436184, 1.87404111122959, 14.9790484066726, 55.5558075106758, 
27.5498161773784, 0.015982408456285, 1.09492181122137, 14.9240206500211, 
70.3603779344479, 13.6046971958534, 0.0451219417000236, 0.982425356030832, 
8.51679586086205, 36.0387787585996, 54.4168780828075, 0.0702840677840961, 
0.905764440477491, 9.7425745252131, 55.0243044728126, 34.2570724937127, 
0.0526280421318409, 1.74861786670406, 12.36074247785, 46.4651383348239, 
39.3728732784902, 0.0439747508150338, 2.01769521292565, 15.4685624145627, 
54.6142357694312, 27.8555318522655, 0.0180283402481118, 1.13230299599989, 
14.645178993385, 69.7263336667268, 14.4781560036402, 0.0464378097181304, 
1.03668408647614, 8.7656126616848, 34.9918299266876, 55.1594355154333, 
0.0631724425493919, 1.00695131172583, 9.57276770796581, 53.321911424454, 
36.035197113305, 0.0558664051609164, 1.84083228549981, 12.6499416767683, 
45.9721967353688, 20.6240488723663, 16.2175663254927, 2.63954769934313, 
0.0470235001449754, 2.11940348282257, 15.7451927739108, 53.7613039185455, 
12.5827542041398, 9.01327347331957, 6.73104864711685, 0.0178654483334489, 
1.12035392197133, 14.1737092566491, 69.3096679260622, 13.7760874515824, 
0.881466349085791, 0.720849646315804, 0.0479739957604947, 1.09480846417636, 
8.96165313142603, 34.1267316833207, 19.6050077304098, 26.4477817971578, 
9.71604319774891, 0.0625792916815526, 0.998704400442457, 9.36385484298694, 
53.4477993412743, 21.7959565707098, 7.13820595107351, 7.19289960183152
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-110L), groups = structure(list(Dato = c("01-23", "01-23", "01-23", 
"01-23", "01-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", "04-23", 
"07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "07-23", "10-23", "10-23", 
"10-23", "10-23", "10-23"), FondskodePlotColumn = c("NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", 
"NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", 
"NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", "NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", 
"RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", "RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816", "NDA 1' 2050 DK0002044551", 
"NYK 1' 2050 DK0009522815", "NYK 5' 2053 DK0009539116", "RD 1' 2050 DK0004612454", 
"RD 5' 2053 DK0004623816"), UdstederKat = c("NDA", "NYK", "NYK", 
"RD", "RD", "NDA", "NYK", "NYK", "RD", "RD", "NDA", "NYK", "NYK", 
"RD", "RD", "NDA", "NYK", "NYK", "RD", "RD"), KuponRente = c(1, 
1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 5), Fondskode = c("DK0002044551", 
"DK0009522815", "DK0009539116", "DK0004612454", "DK0004623816", 
"DK0002044551", "DK0009522815", "DK0009539116", "DK0004612454", 
"DK0004623816", "DK0002044551", "DK0009522815", "DK0009539116", 
"DK0004612454", "DK0004623816", "DK0002044551", "DK0009522815", 
"DK0009539116", "DK0004612454", "DK0004623816"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 21:25, 26:30, 31:35, 36:40, 41:45, 
    46:50, 51:55, 56:60, 61:65, 66:70, 71:75, 76:82, 83:89, 90:96, 
    97:103, 104:110), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), .drop = TRUE))

colors <- c(
  # hatch and bloom
  rgb(0, 69, 123, maxColorValue = 255), 
  rgb(27, 182, 234, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(193, 215, 47, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(247, 143, 30, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(141, 218, 244, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(36, 167, 143, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(204, 28, 85, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(91, 57, 0, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(124, 0, 64, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(103, 101, 47, maxColorValue = 255),
  
  # other colors
  rgb(229, 236, 246, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(127, 162, 189, maxColorValue = 255),
  rgb(64, 116, 156, maxColorValue = 255)
)


 ggplot(df, aes(x = Dato, y = PercentageOfTotal, fill = LoanIntervalMio)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, name = "") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(0.5, 0.5)), position = "top") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = c(0, 0), 
    limits = c(0, 100),  
    labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")  
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~FondskodePlotColumn, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x.top = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
    strip.text = element_text(size = 8),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "right"
  )
```

Comment: My favorite way to get a factor ordered by multiple conditions (including situations where the sorting conditions might be different depending on one of the variables) is to first sort the data into the order I want and then use forcats::fct_inorder() to assign that order to the factor.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I filter the rows and sort them accordingly. But despite using fct_inorder on the column i use in facet_wrap, nothing changes in the plot:

 # Sort
 df <- df %>%
   mutate(UdstederKat = factor(UdstederKat, levels = udsteder_order)) %>%
   arrange(UdstederKat, KuponRente)
 
 # Use forcats::fct_inorder 
 df_factored <- df %>%
   mutate(FondskodePlotColumn = fct_inorder(FondskodePlotColumn))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the key thing is we need to ungroup first, because otherwise every row of the data is within its own group, segregated by `Dato, FondskodePlotColumn, UdstederKat, KuponRente, Fondskode`, so creating a sorting among those variables will be meaningless (it won't "see" any other values for those variables). Once ungrouped, we can first get `UdstederKat` to be sorted correctly (alphabetical default, but with NDA last), then arrange by that and then `KuponRente`, and use the order that combination appears to order the faceting variable.

```
df |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(UdstederKat = factor(UdstederKat) |>
           forcats::fct_relevel("NDA", after = Inf)) |>  
  arrange(UdstederKat, KuponRente) |>
  mutate(FondskodePlotColumn = factor(FondskodePlotColumn) |>
           forcats::fct_inorder()) |>
ggplot(aes(x = Dato, y = PercentageOfTotal, fill = LoanIntervalMio)) +
[the rest of your code]
```

[image]